# Compiling gcc-5.2.0 in RHEL6 with Ada support: "make sure you are using consistent versions of gcc/gnatbind"

Tags: gcc, build, compilation, makefile, ada

Using RHEL6, kernel version `2.6.32-573.3.1.el6.x86_64.`

Configure and make succeed without error.  During the make install process, however:

```
gcc -c -g -O2  -gnatpg -gnatwns  -W -Wall -nostdinc -I- -I. -Iada/generated
-Iada -I../../gcc-5.2.0/gcc/ada -I../../gcc-5.2.0/gcc/ada/gcc-interface
../../gcc-5.2.0/gcc/ada/gnat1drv.adb -o ada/gnat1drv.o

gnatbind -nostdinc -I- -I. -Iada/generated -Iada -I../../gcc-5.2.0/gcc/ada
-I../../gcc-5.2.0/gcc/ada/gcc-interface -o b_gnat1.adb -n ada/gnat1drv.ali

fatal error: file s-stalib.ali is incorrectly formatted
make sure you are using consistent versions of gcc/gnatbind
```

==================================

```
[root@server1 ~]# which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
[root@server1 ~]# which gnatbind
/usr/bin/gnatbind

[root@server1 Notes]# gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16
[root@server1 Notes]# gnatbind --version
GNATBIND 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16)
```

==================================

configure, make, make install are all executed from a separate build directory, NOT the source directory

==================================

```
wget http://mirrors-usa.go-parts.com/gcc/releases/gcc-5.2.0/gcc-5.2.0.tar.gz
tar -xvf gcc-5.2.0.tar.gz
mkdir gcc-5.2.0-build
cd gcc-5.2.0-build
```

==================================

```
../gcc-5.2.0/configure --prefix=/usr/local/pkg/gcc/5.2.0 \
                       --enable-bootstrap \
                       --enable-shared \
                       --enable-threads=posix \
                       --enable-checking=release \
                       --with-system-zlib \
                       --enable-__cxa_atexit \
                       --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada,go \
                       --enable-java-awt=gtk \
                       --with-tune=generic \
                       --with-arch_32=i686 \
                       --build=x86_64-redhat-linux 2>&1 | tee CONFIGURE.OUT
```

==================================

I'm pretty stumped on this.  We used these same configuration options when we installed gcc 4.9.2, on the same server, also this year (no major updates or changes since then), and didn't get this error.

I'm happy to update this question with any other info that may be relevant, please let me know.

Comment: I don't know. But 4.4.7 is a suspiciously old version. If you successfully built and installed gcc4.9.2, I'd suggest using that to build gcc5.2 instead of 4.4.

Comment: Surprising to see ‘make install’ rebuilding the tools. Could it be a path problem? You’re presumably attempting to install as root - does the path change when you change to root?

Comment: @BrianDrummond Thanks, I'll try again with 4.9.2.  For the time being, I simply removed "ada" from the --enable-languages line.  make install is currently running now, seems to be doing much better.  Will have to leave a "Ada is currently unsupported" message for our users till we figure out this problem.

Comment: @SimonWright All steps, configure, make, and make install were run as root.  Nothing weird/out of ordinary with the PATH.  For the time being I just removed "ada" from the languages since the users requesting this latest version of gcc are only interested in c, c++, and fortran.  Still, would like to get Ada support sorted in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your 4.4.7 hosted gcc is too old to directly build 5.2.0. You should try to build first an intermediate version, say 4.8.4, then build the 5.2.0 with the newly built compiler. I succeeded in building 5.2.0 with a 4.7.1 on Slackware.